# How to store directory structure in Oracle sql using java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, tree, structure

I want to store Directory/tree structure to backend from java code. Any one can guide me which way is better to store tree structure to database, here tree structure is not dynamic structure.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend to store in a Composite way. One Parent many childs.

```
ID        Name         parentId
1         parent1      0
2         child11      1
3         child12      1
4         parent2      0
5         child21      4
```

This is the easiest way to store the result.

The directory structure would look like.

```
+parent1
    - child11
    - child12
+patent2
    - child21
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the folder structure representation in DB.

However I am bit confused on how to parse this structure in Java. For example I have following data structure:

- Directory
- - London
- - - FlatFiles
- - - - HOST
- - - - - HostA
- - - - - HostB
- - - - - HostC
- - Europe
- - - FlatFiles
- - - - HOST
- - - - - HostA
- - - - - HostB
- - - - - HostC
- Template
- - London
- - - FlatFiles
- - - - HOST
- - - - - HostA
- - - - - HostB
- - - - - HostC
- - Europe
- - - FlatFiles
- - - - HOST
- - - - - HostA
- - - - - HostB
- - - - - HostC

I have a data that I have to associate a file with HostC under Definition with Location as Europe, so How would that be done. 
If I query whole table via Hibernate, I will get a List of Directory Struture as following:

(1,NULL,RS Root)

(3,1,Directory)

(4,1, Template)

(6,3,London)

(7,6,Flat Files)

(10,7,Host)

(12,10,HostA)

(13,10,HostB)

(14,10,HostTC)

So if I search for HostC I will get many results as per source location(London, Europe) and type(Template, Definition)

How should I traverse it and get the correct branch

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON, Json object can be used as memory structure with-in java. When you need to persist in oracle convert it into jsonString and insert in one of the varChar2 column.

[JASON-LIB](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) supports creation of the tree structure from a String (ie, stored in the database) and the reverse

[Json-Lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)